# How to revert a map of a strsplit?

Tags: r, purrr

```
comb = expand.grid(replicate(2,c(0:2), simplify = F)) %>%
  unite("id",1:2,sep=",") %>%
  mutate(id = map(strsplit(as.character(id), ","),
                       as.numeric))

comb %>%
  mutate(id = map_chr(id,
                     ~paste(.x,sep = ",")))
```

The first part of the code successfully produce a tibble with a list column.
If I want to revert the operation, the code to convert lists columns into characters does not work, why?

Comment: you are using `sep` instead of `collapse = ','`. ie `paste(.x, collapse = ',')` should work